# Is there a way to declare a more specific generic type when overriding properties of a superclass in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I currently have a inheritance hierarchy as follows:

```kotlin
abstract class Foo {
    protected open var elem: Bar<out Foo>? = null
}

class Baz<T : Foo> : Foo {
    override var elem: Bar<out T>? = null
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I try to use this code

```
Var-property is Bar<out T>?, which is not a type of overriden protected open var elem: Bar<out Foo>? defined in Foo
```

I've also tried types such as:

```kotlin
abstract class Foo {
    protected open var elem: Bar<*>? = null
}

class Baz<T : Foo> : Foo {
    override var elem: Bar<out T>? = null
}
```

As well as:

```kotlin
abstract class Foo {
    protected open var elem: Bar<Foo>? = null
}

class Baz<T : Foo> : Foo {
    override var elem: Bar<T>? = null
}
```

However, in each of these cases, I still get similar error messages. I know in Java you can override an inherited variable with a more specific generic type. I'm not very familiar with Kotlin and only recently learned about declaration-site variance, so could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: What's the definition of Bar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a more specific type for a mutable property would break inheritance and polymorphism rules. For example assume this would compile:

```
class A

class B :  A

abstract class Foo {
    protected open var elem: Bar<out A>? = null
}

class Baz : Foo {
    override var elem: Bar<out B>? = null
}
```

Then we have

```
val foo: Foo = Baz()
val producerOfA: Bar<out A> = foo.elem
```

This is correct, the variable expects a producer of `A` and gets one (the specified type is `Bar<out A>` and the actual type is `Bar<out B>`, which is a subtype)

With the same declarations:

```
foo.elem = Bar<out A>()
```

This is incorrect, the setter expects a producer of `A` and gets one, but the underlying type for object `foo` is `Baz()` which accepts only producers of `B` (`Bar<out B>`), and of course a producer of `A` is not always a producer of `B`.

Hope this clears out the issue. You could make it compile by declaring immutable properties (put `val` instead of `var`), but this is use case specific.